Combining Mixamo animations with own animations/rig with specifc bones
I am trying to merge some bones from a Mixamo rig to one of my own armatures. I have only animated the arms in my rig. It is strumming a guitar. But i want to combine everything aside from the arms from an "idle" mixamo animation. So the goal would have the idle standing and swaying from Mixamo, combined with my strumming arms. Is there a way to do this? All i have found are tutorials on how to import Mixamo rigs, or how to retarget the entire armature. I was using Rokoko's retargeting addon, but i couldnt select which bones specifically i wanted to NOT retarget with satisfying results. What is the best option to do what i want to do?
Thanks.
